# Start activity/send intent from object instance within service

Tags: android, object, service, android-intent

I have the following situation: A service is running in the background of my application and regularly receives UDP packets. It uses an instance of my `HandleMessageAgent` class which analyses every message and shall start a new activity if necessary.

I would like to perform the following task: No matter which activity is in the front (as long as the service is running) I would like to inform the user about an incoming message under certain circumstances. I also need to update the information regularly as long as it is valid. Afterwards it should be closed automatically.

At first I thought about using a Dialog, but I think I cannot use it when the activity is not visible. Therefore I decided to use an activity, as it can be started from a service all the time.

I want to start the activity within the `HandleMessageAgent` object (in a method). My problem is, that I do not know how I can define an Intent to start an activity within an object, as the `Context` is not clear to me.

Is there a more elegant way to perform this task? Or can anybody help me with starting an activity from an object method within a service? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two situations to consider:

1. When your service need to notify user your activities are not active, because some other app is active. In this case you should notify user via a system-preferred way: Android Notifications. You should not forcefully show dialogs or activities if user is using some other app. That's what notifications are for.
2. If one of your activities is active (no matter which) then your service should send a broadcast and interested activities should listen for it and act upon it. That way your service will not depend upon specific activity and will not need to keep track which activities are active at the moment the notification must be shown.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To 1): I know the Android Notifications, but unfortunately I cannot use them, because I really need to interrupt the user with an activity. The app is keeping track of traffic situations I the user needs to be focused on a new situation if necessary.

Comment: To 2): If I exactly know the Activity to start, I can also use an Intent, can't I? And my problem is the object which performs the action. Can I pass the application context to the constructor of the object, to internally use it for starting the activity?

Comment: You can use `getApplication()` in you service.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your object Parcelable and add it to the Intent that will start the Activity.
Or you can put it in a subclass of Application because that instance is shared between your activities and your services (as long as they're in the same process)

You might need the "START_NEW_TASK" flag on the Intent

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to send my object. I want to send a message from WITHIN my object (method in my object) and this object is instantiated in my service. I am passing the application context to the constructor.

Comment: Well a Context instance allows you to launch any activity you want using startActivity. Isn't that what you're looking for ? So, in your constructor, you can pass you Service instance, the Application instance; i'm not sure the ApplicationContext instance allows it.